# Flicker using Word 2013

Tags: windows, microsoft-word-2013

I just installed Office 2013 Professional Plus yesterday. I have a NVIDIA GTX 690 GPU. Today is the first time I actually used Word 2013. I just noticed that there is flickering whenever I scroll the page up or down. It's not a heavy screen flicker. It's the graphics or text in the document flickering when I scroll, as though it's too slow and can't catch up with the page scroll. I can't believe MS would release something like this.

In any case, I tried Microsoft's [recommended fixes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2768648), but to no avail. Any ideas? It's killing my eyes.

Comment: Which of those fixes did you actually try?  I.e. Did you update your video driver?

Comment: I installed 2670838 and disabled the graphics acceleration. I wasn't going to reinstall the GPU driver. I just did that about 2 weeks ago. It's okay though. I'm back to Office 2010 until MS gets the flickering problems and extreme whiteness of Office 2013 sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flickering/vibration/wiggles problem has happened to me on several occasions, always after an AMD update, and affecting some files not all.

Maximizing the screen size and saving the file corrects the problem for me. I have no idea why it works; it just does.

Note: I am using Word 2010 on a PC.

Answer (score 0):

From within MS Word (or Excel if you're having the problem there)

- File
- Options
- Advanced
- Scroll down to the Display section
- Disable hardware graphics acceleration [check this option]

Fixes the problem instantly !